# como arreglar error unauthorized al conectar un dispositivo android y ejecutando adb devices

Tags: android, adb

al conectar mi telefono habilitando el modo depuracion usb al computador y ejecutar el adb devices me sale este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
al intentar adb kill-server y adb start-server para volver a conectar el cel ma sale este mensaje

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y al volver a ejecutar el adb devices me sigue saliendo unauthorized

ya intente revocando los permisos de depuracion y volviendo a activar el modo depuracion por usb, y matando el servidor y volviendolo a iniciar con el cel conectado y desconectado

Comment: update: ya solucione el problema es que no se habia insalado el google usb driver el cual no permitia mostrar en el dispositivo la notificacion para aceptar el computador como dispositivo autorizado para el debugging, igual gracias por la respuestas :)